# proof: the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, and find $\lim x_n$. (check)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

proof: the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, and find $\lim x_n$. (check).

Question: Suppose $x_1= \frac 12$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n^2$. Show that $\{x_n\}$ converges and find $\lim x_n$. Hint: you cannot divide by zero!

From the question, I know that $\{x_n\}=\{\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 1{16}, ....\} = \{\frac 1{2^{2^n}}: n\in N\}$.

Then, $\lim x_n = 0$. So, to test convergence, let $\varepsilon > \frac 1{2^{2^M}}$, and $M \in N$. Then, for $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $M$ such that$|\frac 1{2^{2^n}}-0|<\varepsilon $ for $n\ge M$ because $2^{2^M}\le2^{2^n} \rightarrow \frac 1{2^{2^M}}\ge \frac 1{2^{2^n}} \rightarrow \frac 1{2^{2^n}}<\varepsilon$.

Could you check this proof is fine? I am not sure about my answer since I don't know when I make use of hint.

Thank you in advance.

I edited. Thanks for pointing out. Could you check anything wrong??

Comment: You might want to check the third term of your sequence... it certainly isn't $1/2^3$!

Comment: You made a mistake in the calculation of your sequence it's  $\{x_n\} = \{ \frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 1{16}, \frac 1{16^2} .....  \}$

Comment: Further, your statement "$\lim x_n = 0$" is what you are trying to prove, so you can't use it in your next steps, but you are pretty close. Your aim is to find an $N$ for every $\varepsilon$ such that $|x_n - 0| < \varepsilon$. Try to do that.

Comment: I was also thinking that it is wrong to use $\lim x_n =0$ before I prove the convergence. But, without assuming $\lim x_n =0$, is it allowed to say $|x_n-0|< \varepsilon$??

Comment: yeah, because you suppose it, then the whole estimation thing with the $|x_n-0|< \varepsilon$ term is the proof to your assumption.

Comment: Ok. So do you mean I should say "suppose $lim x_n=0$. Then, $|x_n-0|< \varepsilon$"?

Comment: Something like this: " We aim to prove $lim x_n=0$, so we consider $|x_n-0|< \varepsilon$ for any given $\varepsilon > 0$." Now you got to find a fitting $N$ so that $|x_n-0|< \varepsilon$ for every $n \ge N$.....

Comment: I got it . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Careful! $$ x_{n+1}= x_n^2 $$

This  $$\{x_n\}=\{\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18, ....\} = \{\frac 1{2^n}:n>0, n\in N\}$$

is not correct.

You do not have a $1/8$ after $1/4$

you get $ (1/4)^2= 1/16 $

Also  your sequence is not

$$\{\frac 1{2^n}:n>0, n\in N\}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the well known Bolzano's lemma: "A monotonic decreasing sequence that is bounded below is convergent ". The boundedness is clear since $x_n > 0, \forall n \ge 1$. The monotone part is also clear since $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 < x_n, \forall n \ge 1$ since you can check by induction that $x_n \le 1/2, \forall n \ge 1$. From this the lemma is invoked and it says: $L = L^2 \implies L = 0$ or $L = 1$. Since $L \le 1/2, L = 0$ .